# determining size of array that is formed via calculation

Tags: matlab

I am creating a 1 dimensional row array via a calculation

```
  Lt_p= totalLn_p - ln_p
```

Which returns

```
 Lt_p =

4.4408    4.3482    3.9962    3.4517    2.9009    2.3447    2.0648    1.7837    1.5015         1.0676    0.8665    0.6739    0.4822    0.2818    0.0820         0
```

Due to the nature of the calculation the last element will always be 0, I then need to use Lt_p in another calculation (by dividing it by another array).

However the other array will always have one less element than Lt_p, so obviously can not be divided.

The 0 element is not needed though so how do I resize Lt_p to not include the last element?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that you will not need it? Otherwise a zero element is a good way determining the end of the data. Either you do as Divakar in the comment, otherwise you define an array `ind = Lt_p(1:end-1)`. And always calls Lt_p(ind). The latter is of course a waste of resources and computation time if you is completely sure you will only need elements `Lt_p(1:end-1)`.